# Can we have recaptcha V2 in IOS mobile app developed using ionic/angular

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, recaptcha

We have an Angular based ionic mobile application. Is there a way I can add recaptcha v2 for a page in the mobile App?

If yes, let me know the steps.

I am unable to find a suitable article for my situation

I tried in recaptcha enterprise. But unable to figure out how to create a private key, Team Id etc.

Comment: Please see [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/instrument-ios-apps) for integrating reCAPTCHA with your iOS app.

Comment: @CoryKramer thank you. So your point is that we should not use V2 recaptcha for mobile as it is not meant for it, even though there are articles that has solutions to make v2 recaptcha work in mobile. Can you please confirm?

Comment: PS:- I am not sure if the methods available in net to make v2 recaptcha work for mobile is the appropriate or not